# help me eliminate a for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

There has to be a faster way of doing this.

There is a lot going on here, but it's fairly straightforward to unpack.

Here is the relevant python code (from scipy import *)

```
for i in arange(len(wav)):
    result[i] = sum(laser_flux * exp(-(wav[i] - laser_wav)**2) )
```

There are a bunch of arrays.

- result -- array of length (wav)
- laser_flux -- array of length (laser)
- wav -- array of length (wav)
- laser_wav -- array of length (laser)

Yes, within the exponential, I am squaring (element by element) the difference between the scalar value and the array of laser_wav.

Everything works as expected (including SLOWLY) any help you can give me to eliminate this for-loop would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tip: include complete, runnable sample code, so people don't have to spend time parsing out what's what, and so everyone has the same sample inputs and outputs to compare.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I doubt the usefulness of my answer, but feel it's worth pointing out in a comment.

Does Python have linear algebra libraries? If so, it may be faster to express your squaring/summing as a matrix multiplication. Just a brainstorm-style idea to consider.

Answer (score 13):

You're going to want to use Numpy arrays (if you're not already) to store your data.  Then, you can take advantage of array broadcasting with `np.newaxis`.  For each value in `wav`, you're going to want to compute a difference between that value and each value in `laser_wav`.   That suggests that you'll want a two-dimensional array, with the two dimensions being the `wav` dimension and the `laser` dimension.

In the example below, I'll pick the first index as the `laser` index and the second index as the `wav` index.  With sample data, this becomes:

```
import numpy as np

LASER_LEN  = 5
WAV_LEN    = 10
laser_flux = np.arange(LASER_LEN)
wav        = np.arange(WAV_LEN)
laser_wav  = np.array(LASER_LEN)

# Tile wav into LASER_LEN rows and tile laser_wav into WAV_LEN columns
diff    = wav[np.newaxis,:] - laser_wav[:,np.newaxis]
exp_arg = -diff ** 2
sum_arg = laser_flux[:,np.newaxis] * np.exp(exp_arg)

# Now, the resulting array sum_arg should be of size (LASER_LEN,WAV_LEN)
# Since your original sum was along each element of laser_flux/laser_wav, 
# you'll need to sum along the first axis.
result = np.sum(sum_arg, axis=0)
```

Of course, you could just condense this down into a single statement:

```
result = np.sum(laser_flux[:,np.newaxis] * 
                np.exp(-(wav[np.newaxis,:]-laser_wav[:,np.newaxis])**2),axis=0)
```

Edit:

As noted in the comments to the question, you can take advantage of the "sum of multiplications" inherent in the definition of linear-algebra style multiplications.  This then becomes:

```
result = np.dot(laser_flux, 
    np.exp(-(wav[np.newaxis,:] - laser_wav[:,np.newaxis])**2))
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that using numpy will be **much** faster than any pure Python alternative. numpy executes its calculations in C.

Comment: That is *definitely* true - I noticed an enormous speedup when I made this type of change in one of my applications.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Python, so this may not the most optimal *in Python*, but I'd use the same technique for Perl, Scheme, etc.

```
def func(x):
    delta = x - laser_wav
    return sum(laser_flux * exp(-delta * delta))
result = map(func, wav)
```

Comment: wouldn't the function call to sq(x) add some time?  it might be more to write but if you're really worried about speed it seems like actually writing out the x*x would be better than calling the function once.

Comment: I believe it's generally considered more pythonic thse days to use a list comprehension instead of `map()`.  But I can't really see either solution providing a _significant_ (or even measurable?) speed increase..

Comment: @Casey: I've removed sq, for that reason.
@John: You're probably right, but I'm really unfamiliar with list comprehensions, because I'm much more used to languages with map (Perl, Scheme, etc.). But thanks for the tip!

Comment: result = [func(x) for x in wav]

Comment: `func()` does not return anything. So `result` will be a list of `None`s.

Comment: @rubik: Thanks for the heads-up, this is now fixed. So, Python joins languages like JS where you have to explicitly say return. (I think it's stupid; I prefer languages like Ruby, Perl, and Scheme where the last value is implicitly returned, but that's my functional programmer self speaking there.)

Answer (score 1):

If raw performance is an issue, you might benefit from rewriting to take advantage of multiple cores, if you have them.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5) # about the number of cores you have

def f(i):
    delta = wav[i] - laser_wav
    return sum(laser_flux * exp(-delta*delta) )

result = p.map(f, arange(len(wav)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it seems to be slightly quicker to multiply a variable by itself than to use the `**` power operator:

```
~$ python -m timeit -n 100000 -v "x = 4.1; x * x"
raw times: 0.0904 0.0513 0.0493
100000 loops, best of 3: 0.493 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit -n 100000 -v "x = 4.1; x**2"
raw times: 0.101 0.147 0.118
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 usec per loop
```

Comment: If you're doing optimizations at this level, you're really close to where you should be writing a native module to handle the math.  There might be higher-level optimizations to be made, though (waiting on sample data before I look)...